# Is it possible to cause an exception-like state in C that can be try-catched in a higher level programming language?

Tags: c, exception

Two cases:

1. Is it possible to do when embedding C source code into another higher-level programming language, such as C++/Object-C/Java?
2. Is is possible to do when compiling a library to use in another higher-level programming language, such as C#/JavaScript (WebAssembly)?

I am aware of the existence of `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`, but I'm not sure if they can be used to implement that particular behavior.

Comment: Depends on the interface of your host langauge. Per example, if your C code is run in erlang and you you want it to raise an exception, you call `enif_raise_exception()`. For Java, you can call the `ThrowNew` function of the `JNIEnv`.

Comment: My take-away from that is that it is possible if you know which programming language you are targetting and can use functions available in that language, but probably not if you want to make a general solution - correct?

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed by the C or C++ standards, but in practice you probably can call a C++ function that throws an exception, and catch it in anotger C++ function, even if there are C functions in between. You will need to make sure this does not create memory leaks or messes up your program state (these things could also happen with `longjmp` so nothing new here). In practice this means no dynamic allocations or complex operations with externally visible state in your C code

Comment: There is absolutely no way whatsoever to make it in a language/compiler/OS-independent way.

Comment: @n.m. does that apply to both cases? How about creating a state with `setjmp()/longjmp()` that can be detected in the higher-level programming languages, but not actually as an exception (simply just to avoid returning error codes through the call stack)?

Comment: If your high level language supports calling C functions, you can call setjmp and longjmp. This may or may not mess up your program state completely, dependding on what exactly you are doing and how your labguage in question works.

Comment: A generic (higher-language independent) method would require a _design_ that lets the lower-level C part _communicate_ a "catcheable state" to the calling language.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie yessss, that's what I'm asking if exists (perhaps through `setjmp()/longjmp()`.

Comment: You can use `setjmp/longjmp` _within_ the C code. Upon longjmp the C code activates the designed catch functionality (still in the C code) which communicates the "catcheable state" to the calling language. The calling language implements a "catcheable state" handler and then uses its own mechanisms further to handle the "catch".

Comment: If you want a practical advice, here's one, condensed to minimum words. **Don't**.

Comment: The short answer is "no".   A longer and only partially correct answer is that it is possible if the compiler/interpreter of the "higher level language" and the C compiler/interpreter are SPECIFICALLY designed to interoperate.   If that's true, their documentation will say so, and describe how to do it.   But using such a feature will often mean your code will only work with those specific compilers/interpreters (sometime even specific versions of them), and (if you're lucky) not even build with other compilers/interpreters or (if you're unlucky) build but behave differently in subtle ways.